# Google Chromebook - low power charger

Tags: usb, chromebook

I recently purchased a USB A to USB C cable. I'm using this cable with a Chromebook and the adapter identifies as "low power charger". Is there a way within Google Chrome OS to view the amount of miliamps that are flowing to this device?

Thanks,
Jeff

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no. Most electronics, including laptops, chromebooks and tablets do not have a digital amperage meter  (ammeter) .

The  charging system does detect that a charger cannot supply enough current and falls back to the slowest charge mode, then indicates this to the OS afterwards. Which is what is happening with your cable. But the OS doesn't receive an exact mA reading. You need an external method for this.

There are actually [USB ammeters](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=usb%20ammeter&ref=nb_sb_noss_1) sold on amazon and other websites. You can use these to obtain an exact reading.